# Python: how to find unique nodes between two networks in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unique, networkx

I have two networks `G` and `G1` that are generated with `networkx`.

In order to find a list containing unique nodes between the two networks (i.e. intersection), I run in `Python 2.7` the following command which works perfectly.

```
tmp2 =  list(set(G.nodes) & set(G1.nodes))
```

The same command in a machine with `Python 3` returns the following error:

```
TyperError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way to avoid this error in `Python 3.x`?

Comment: I created a simple network and could not reproduce your issue, which means you have not provided a [mcve].  Your code works fine for me in Python 3, networkx version 2.1.  Can you please post your version of networkx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In networkx version 1.x, `G.nodes` is a method, and it returns the nodes of `G`.  `G.nodes()` is a list of nodes of `G`.  So your call to `set(G.nodes)` is asking Python to make a set out of a method.  That can't be done.  It can make a set out of the nodes of `G`.  So `set(G.nodes())` works.

In version 2.x, `G.nodes` and `G.nodes()` both are `NodeView` objects.  These operate a lot like lists (though there are differences).

Thus your command will run in the most recent version of networkx, but not in older versions.  Even if you switch to using `2.x`, I recommend still calling it as `G.nodes()` in case the code is ever run in an earlier version.

Answer (score 3):

The error suggests that `nodes` is a method in Python 3 so the code should be changed to `list(set(G.nodes()) & set(G1.nodes()))` in order to actually call it.